# PhpStorm: is there a way to view diff of a merge-commit?

Tags: phpstorm

Merge-commits show no changes when I view git history in PhpStorm. However, Github shows them.

[image]

How can I view them in the PhpStorm directly?

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/viewing-modes.html